# how to match word in single line using Boost Regex?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have four words, in a single line, separated by **`\n`**. e.g.: `"aa\ne'sboob\ng-coo\nood\nff"`  (Note, words may contains not only English letters, but containing no '\n'!)

I want do partial match at word level:e.g. partial match `"oo"` gives me `"boob", "coo", and "ood"`.

I started with pattern: `"^(.*?oo.*?)$"`, which gives me: `"aa\ne'sboob", "g-coo", and "ood"`. Obviously `"aa\ne'sboob"` is wrong.

I am using Boost Regex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{    
    std::vector<std::string> v; 
    std::string text = "aa\ne'sboob\ng-coo\nood\nff";

    const char* pattern = "^(.*?oo.*?)$";
    boost::regex reg(pattern);
        boost::sregex_iterator it(text.begin(), text.end(), reg);
        boost::sregex_iterator end;
    std::string tmp;
        for (; it != end; ++it) {
        tmp = it->str();
        v.push_back(it->str());
            std::cout << tmp << std::endl;
        }
    std::cout << "total find: " << v.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can please help me on this?

**EDIT**:
I have one pattern work, but I do not understand it. Please also help explain. 
Note: perhaps I need help on use Boost regex properly.

**EDIT**:
Clarifying that words may contain not only English letters. Also update the source as @just-somebody suggested.

Many thanks

Comment: you say: _I have four words, in a single line, separated by **`/n`**. e.g.: `"aa\nboob\ncoo\nood\nff"`_.  there's no `/n` in the string, and it contains 4.5 lines.

Comment: Typo, Sorry! Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this pattern works fine for me:

```
"^([^\\n.]*?oo.*?)$"
```

But I am expecting more elegant solutions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `.*` in your regex when you want `[a-z]*`

Comment: Thanks for this. `"aa\nboob\ncoo\nood\nff"` is an example, in real life, I do not know what's there. But I know it is *NOT* `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

`\b\w*oo\w*\b` should help.  [Perl Regular Expression Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html).

**edit** since the OP contends the answer...

i did these changes to the code as posted:

- added `#include <boost/regex.hpp>`
- changed the function to `int main(void)`
- changed the pattern to `const char* pattern = "\\b\\w*oo\\w*\\b";`

compiled, ran, and got:

```
boob
coo
ood
total find: 3
```

Comment: how did the result differ from your expectations?  maybe your question is not as clear as you have hoped and i have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: actually, it gives me nothing. I've listed the source. You may need add dependency to boost regex header to compile it.

Comment: perhaps you forgot that you need to double the backslashes for the regular expression to survive the funneling through the C++ string literal?

Comment: Many thanks for your time! I have to say my question is not precise. In fact, @paul-evans has suggested matching only word "[a-z]" rather than anything ".". I replied him, but forgot to update the question. Sorry I cannot accept yours as an answer. I've updated the question.